# Dynamic margins using css

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, background, margin

I'm quite new to web-design, but know most of the basic stuff, but please try to keep it relatively simple) So, I'm designing a web-site, where I want to have grey background on the sides of the main page, which I managed to do. However, I want the page to "eat up" the grey space if the window is resized, just like [Marriott hotel](http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/lonpr-st-pancras-renaissance-london-hotel) uses I have tried looking their code up, but it's a lot and I don't think they use CSS but JavaScript for resizing dynamics. Am I right? If so, is there a way of doing it with CSS? Or java, but relatively simple, I'm very new to it!

Also, I have currently given the wrapper a width of `88%` and used the `12%` as the grey background. Is using `%` the best solution for different screen resolutions? (Keeping in mind that it would be for PCs and tablets at the most, no smartphones)

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript, not Java...

Comment: Are they not the same?) Haha, sorry, like I said - I'm new to the whole programming thing! Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

Using percentages can be useful, but if you truly want things to look how you want them to on a smaller screen resolution, you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Media queries work well because they can even change the styles depending on device orientation:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

[**Using a media query**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mhLb65d/). (Make the window bigger & smaller to see it in action.)

Comment: Okay, that looks little more complicated than I was hoping for, but seems like I'll be using that anyway. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's truly not that complicated. If you ever get stuck then just Google it and you'll find loads of tutorials on media queries! Good luck! @Tony

Comment: Okay, different question then: what's a better practice - including different media queries in 'global' stylesheet or having different stylesheets load depending on the media query? What's more robust / what would you go for?

Comment: It's up to you honestly! Just what people prefer. I personally keep it in one big 'global' stylesheet so I know where it all is! @Tony

Comment: I've decided to do the same after looking at major web-sites. Thanks! 
Aaaand I have another question already! Is it possible to define the width as 88% and assign a rule for 100% if max-width: 1100px; or do my widths have to be in pixels now? I've tried both - and it only works if I use pixels, not %.

Comment: It should work for both. Sorry for the late reply! Was the weekend! @Tony

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the following:

1. Add a background to the body.
2. Add a div with X px and margin auto, that will center it.

So then, when you resize the window, this will "eat" the margins from the body hidding the grey background.

If what you want is different sizes for the web depending on the width screen, then you are entering to media queries.

Comment: That's the problem, I want to avoid giving pixel dimensions since the resolutions vary a lot, from 900px to like 2000px on big screens. That's why I originally started with %.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcvbkv5w/

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left:0%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
#fwcenter {
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 700px){ 
 #fwcenter{
     width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <center>
    <div id="fwcenter">
      <div id="container">
        Website content
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but I'm trying to do it in % rather than pixels, so it looks good on all sizes of screens. 800 would look funny on a screen with 2000px resolution

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
#wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

This will place your wrapper (with a 900px width) with even margins on the side and then recalculate the margins as the window changes.

I would give your wrapper a set width since setting a width of 88% means that the center content will ALWAYS be 88% of the window which means you will always have margins.

Comment: Would it work if I set a minimum width in pixels? Would it overwrite the % rule? Say 88%? but the min-width: 900px?

Comment: Yes. That would mean your wrapper would always occupy 88% of the browser until it tried to go below 900px. At which point the wrapper would simply stick to the 900px width.

Comment: Ah, but it would not eat up the grey space, it would just create a horizontal scroll, I see. Thanks!